# What DNS TXT records do I need?

Tags: nginx, dns, cpanel, cloudflare, mern

I have a website hosted on a cPanel, I need to change it to Cloudflare nameservers and then the dns records so the main domain will be pointed to a vps ip address and the mx records keep using cPanel records. The problem is I found a lot of TXT records created by the cPanel and I don't know what I should take or leave since they look so random.

My cPanel DNS Zone Editor:
[image: My cPanel DNS Zone Editor]

**Notice:**
I have two active domains on my cPanel, the first is the main domain which I would like to transfer to point to my vps, the second should keep working on the cPanel. but I found related txt records in the first domain, looks like this  caldav._tcp.DOMAIN2.tn.DOMAIN1.tn. (check screenshot)? Why does it even exists in the main domain records?

I just need to move the main domain and keep the mailing service with cPanel! Which TXT records should I create on Cloudflare after I change the domain nameservers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on keeping your eMail where it is but only plan on changing the web site to use CloudFlare you should really leave ALL of these TXT records as they are.

SPF = Sender Policy Framework (which is a list of servers or services that can send eMail using your domain name)
DKIM = Domain Key Identified Mail (is a form of anti-alteration system to stop eMails being altered in transit)

DKIM is unique to each domain and subdomain so if you have a eMail service on the second domain you should have an SPF & DKIM record for them too.

As for the bottom rules I don't know what they are.